# Different behaviour of the ElementMenu in Microsoft Surface 2

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, menu, pixelsense

I was following this [tutorial](http://codepronet.blogspot.fr/2009/05/elementmenu-in-microsoft-surface.html) to create an ElementMenu on the Microsoft Surface 2.

This tutorial was made for the Microsoft Surface 1, and showing as result this scrrenshot

[image]

I did the same thing in the Microsoft Surface 2, and I got this result :

[image]

Is this a normal behaviour on Microsoft Surface 2 for the ElementMenu ?

Do I need to do something else to get the same result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the normal behavior, and apparently it cannot be changed by using styles or control templates. The issue has been discussed [on Microsoft Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/de4219f9-f761-4ebe-b63b-94f5e955daf0).